# How to lower case part of file with awk?

Tags: awk

I have a lot of files, which contain lines such as

```
local1 = "AAA"
private = "Filename_With_Uppercase"
```

where I would like to change the right side of the equal side to only lower case. But only for lines that start with `private`.

If I do

```
gawk -F'=' '/^private/{gsub(/[-/]/, "_"); tolower($2)} 1' filename
```

then it doesn't change anything...

**Question**

Can anyone figure out why the right hand side of the equal side isn't converted to lower case?

Comment: You need to either `$2=tolower($2)` or `print $1,tolower($2)` and mind the `OFS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*why the right hand side of the equal side isn't converted to lower case?*

[`tolower(string)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function does

> Return a copy of *string*, with each uppercase character in the string
> replaced with its corresponding lowercase character. Nonalphabetic
> characters are left unchanged.

So you need to assign it back to get visible effect, i.e. `$2=tolower($2)` rather than just `tolower($2)` and also set FS to OFS to avoid replacing `=` with   i.e.

```
'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}/^private/{gsub(/[-/]/, "_");$2=tolower($2)} 1'
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F'^private = ' 'BEGIN{OFS="private = "} NF>=2{$2=tolower($2)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, making `^private =`  as a field separator for all lines here. Then setting `OFS` to `private =`  for all lines. In main program checking if number of fields are more or equal to 2 then changing whole 2nd field to lower case as per requirement and printing the edited/non-edited lines then.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually **use** the value returned by `tolower()`, it's not like `[g]sub()` where it modifies it's argument it's more like `substr()` in that it returns the modified string, see the awk manual.

Any solution that is working with `$2` or otherwise relies on fields being split on `=` will fail when your file names contain `=` signs. This is how to work with tag=value pairs of input data:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/ *=.*/,"",tag)
}
tag == "private" {
    sub(/[^=]+ *= */,"",val)
    gsub(/[-/]/,"_",val)
    $0 = tag " = " tolower(val)
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
local1 = "AAA"
private = "filename_with_uppercase"
```

The above assumes that, as in your example, there's no leading white space in your input - it's an easy tweak to handle it if there is.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using `gnu awk`, it can be done in a single step in `gensub` function:

```sh
awk -F= '/^private/ {$2 = gensub(/[-/]/, "_", "g", tolower($2))} 1' file

local1 = "AAA"
private   "filename_with_uppercase"
```